# SQL join including all rows from one table irrespective of how many are represented in the other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

[image: Tables]

I want to output the following:

[image: Desired output]

I tried this statement:

```
SELECT TableA.bu_code
     , SUM(TableB.count_invalid_date) AS TotalInvDate 
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.bu_code = TableB.bu_code 
GROUP BY TableA.bu_code
```

But it doesn't show every row represented in TableA, instead it does this:

[image: Actual output]

Is there a single SQL statement that can output what I want?

Comment: Your SQL statement is correct for keeping all rows in `TableA`.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  You would appear to have another problem.

Comment: Impossible. It should fetch all the rows from `tableA`

Comment: are you sure there are no white spaces `bu_code` column values?

Comment: SQL Fiddle added - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0ed71/1
Now the odd thing is that the SQL Fiddle seems to work fine - it returns rows where there are nulls, but in SQL 2012, nothing is returned.  I even tried doing this in MS Access (mde) and got the same results (only one result returned).

Comment: I confess that I simplified my tables greatly to attempt to reproduce the issue on a smaller subset.  After taking the SQL Fiddle and creating the reduced recordset in SQL 2012 it appears to work as expected.  I will take a closer look at my original data and see if I can find the issue, if I can't, I'll repost with updated (live) data that I'm using.  Thank you all for your help!

Comment: What version of SQL Server is applicable to this `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `left join` **after** performing the `group by`:

```
SELECT    a.bu_code, COALESCE (TotalInvDate, 0)
FROM      TableA a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   bu_code, SUM(count_invalid_date) AS TotalInvDate
           FROM     TableB
           GROUP BY bu_code) b ON a.bu_code = b.bu_code
```

Comment: How is this different from OP's query

Answer (score 0):

There may be orphaned TableB rows without a parent row in TableA.

If so, use this GROUP BY syntax to see them.

```
GROUP BY ROLLUP(TableA.bu_code)
```

Refer to this [Microsoft SQL-Server page on the `GROUP BY` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) for more details on the ROLLUP option.

Comment: Thanks - it doesn't solve my issue but it's useful information nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.bu_code AS [bu_code],
       ISNULL(sum( B.count_invalid_date),0) AS [TotalInvDate]
FROM 
         TableA A 
left JOIN 
         TableB B 
ON 
         A.bu_code=B.bu_code
GROUP BY 
         A.bu_code
```