# SQL join including all rows from one table irrespective of how many are represented in the other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following on from my previous question [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648578/sql-join-including-all-rows-from-one-table-irrespective-of-how-many-are-represen?noredirect=1#comment45596801_28648578).

I have two tables:

TableA

[image: TableA]

TableB

[image: TableB]

I want to output the following:

[image: Desired Output]

Instead, my query gives me this:

[image: Current Output]

Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT TableA.BU, TableB.count_invalid_date
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.BU = TableB.BU 
WHERE TableB.Month = 8
GROUP BY TableA.BU, TableB.count_invalid_date;
```

Is there a single SQL statement that can give me what I want?
SQL Fiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ab0f/1
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  TableA.BU, 
  TableB.count_invalid_date 
FROM 
  TableA 
  LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.BU = TableB.BU and TableB.Month = 8 
GROUP BY 
  TableA.BU, 
  TableB.count_invalid_date;
```

When doing an outer join, you can't reference any of the table in where clause or otherwise it will turn it into inner join.

Comment: Wow!  JamesZ!  Talk about quick, I can't even mark it as correct yet - I have to wait 8 minutes but THANK YOU!!!  This did the trick.  End of!

Answer (score 3):

**Problem:**

Since your `where` clause says `TableB.Month=8`, that is why other rows are getting eliminated from the result.

**Solution:**

Add one more condition to the `where` clause.

```
SELECT TableA.BU, TableB.count_invalid_date 
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN
     TableB ON TableA.BU=TableB.BU
WHERE (TableB.Month=8 OR TableB.Month IS NULL)
GROUP BY TableA.BU, TableB.count_invalid_date;
```

Result:

```
BU      COUNT_INVALID_DATE
APAC    (null)
EMEA    3
SG      (null)
US      (null)
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/089085/7).